# iOS 8: Make a view common as a footer on all view controllers in app

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uiwindow

I have an application built using storyboards, I have a requirement that I have to place a view as a footer in all view controllers which will contain the same (persistent) information in all screens. I have tried to add it in container view in a separate view controller, & then embed that view controller in navigation bar ( [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758420/making-a-button-persistent-across-all-view-controllers)). But this didn't provide me any help. Can anyone help me with any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer to this question. You can use a similar approach expect place it at the bottom instead of the top.

[Add a topbar to iOS application visible to all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553579/add-a-topbar-to-ios-application-visible-to-all-views/27553903#27553903)

Comment: Do you have any sample project on this?

Comment: No I do not, but if you follow the screenshot it should be straightforward to reproduce.

Comment: What exactly have you taken in this? & from where you referred what? Can you tell the heirarchy?

Comment: RootViewController has two embedded UIContainerViews. Those point to two different UIViewControllers

Comment: Done any changes for coding part?

Comment: Not able to get that... :(

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [this link](https://github.com/saikirank/CustomFooterMenuForEntireApp) for achieving common footer implementation using container view concept.