# Extend UIViewController's UI down to children UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a base view controller `BaseUIViewController` which is extended from `UIViewController`. I have two `UIButtons` at the bottom of this ViewController. Basically I want these two buttons on every `UIViewController` at the same place through out my app.  When I extend `BaseUIViewController`, I don't see them in the children view controllers. 
I have given IBOutlets to the buttons too!
I am new to programming. Please help. Isn't this way inheritance work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [UIViewControllerContainment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). This [Stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553579/add-a-topbar-to-ios-application-visible-to-all-views/27553903#27553903) post explains it in detail how you can create it and make it work. Similalry, also have a look at this [Stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758420/making-a-button-persistent-across-all-view-controllers/17759156#17759156) post. Here it is done using childViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put these button properties in `@interface` instead of `@implement`, only properties in `@interface` can see in subclasses. Here is example:

```
@interface BaseUIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the ways which MUNAHIL answered above, are the best ones I believe. In case you want to achieve this in a more basic way, you can do as below.

- Add the two `UIButton`s in the `BaseUIViewController` (either programmatically in viewDidLoad or in storyboard). In case you need, you may like to add a UIToolBar first and then the buttons on top of it.
- Make other view controllers a subclass of `BaseUIViewController`.

  ```
  @interface SomeViewController: BaseUIViewController
  ```
- Now, all your view controllers will have the two buttons by default.